# How does grid or ring (coupling map topology) affect the depth of the circuit?

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, quantum-state

Why does different grid maps have different depths, i.e why does a 10x10 grid has more depth than 10x3. Also how does topology affect the depth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coupling map shape affects circuit depth because a processes that is sometime called *routing*. If a circuit has a $CX(0,2)$ (a cnot entanglement between qubits 0 and 2), but the coupling map does not connect qubits 0 and 2 directly, the routing process needs to introduce a $SWAP$ gate to allow the entanglement, increasing the depth of the cirucit.

At least in [Qiskit](https://qiskit.org/), **the routing process is a stochastic process**. Transpiling into a 10x10 grid should result in equal or less depth than into a 10x3 grid, because 10x3 is subgraph of 10x10. That is, **on average**. You should run the same process several times with different seeds to explore that, because [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).

Similarly, a ring of a side that allows it to be included in a grid should be more restrictive. Therefore, on average, the grid should result in a non-deeper circuit.

Here an example:

```
circuit = QuantumVolume(6, seed=42)
depths3x3 = []
for seed in range(100):
    result = transpile(circuit, coupling_map=CouplingMap.from_grid(3,3), initial_layout=[0,1,2,5,4,3], seed_transpiler=seed)
    depths3x3.append(result.depth())
depths2x3 = []
for seed in range(100):
    result = transpile(circuit, coupling_map=CouplingMap.from_grid(2,3), initial_layout=[0,1,2,5,4,3], seed_transpiler=seed)
    depths2x3.append(result.depth())
print('3x3:', mean(depths3x3))
print('2x3:', mean(depths2x3))
```

Notice that specific instances might look contradicting (`max(depths3x3)` vs `min(depths2x3)`) but that is the general rule.

Also notice that the fixed the initial layout to be the same. Otherwise, in a bigger grid, the transpiler has more options to allocate the qubits in the circuit, an that might end up in worst results. If both coupling maps have the same size, that is not a problem. Compare here a 2x3-grid and a ring-6:

```
depths_ring6 = []
for seed in range(100):
    result = transpile(circuit, coupling_map=CouplingMap.from_ring(6), seed_transpiler=seed)
    depths_ring6.append(result.depth())
depths_grid2x3 = []
for seed in range(100):
    result = transpile(circuit, coupling_map=CouplingMap.from_grid(2,3), initial_layout=[0,1,2,5,4,3], seed_transpiler=seed)
    depths_grid2x3.append(result.depth())
print('ring-6:', mean(depths_ring6))
print('grid-2x3:', mean(depths_grid2x3))
```

```
ring-6: 10
grid-2x3: 9.15
```

Again, specific instances can be particularly bad (`min(depths_ring6)` is 10, and `max(depths_grid2x3)` is 12). But you got the point.

Not every circuit compiler is stochastic. This explanation only applies to stochastic circuit compilers, such as Qiskit.

Comment: I want to know why that affects the depth, i.e what is theory or explanation behind the depth change due to topology? For example if I transpire two different quantum circuits with the two different grids let's say 2x2 and 2x3 why is the average depth different for both circuit for different coupling maps.

Comment: I added a paragraph on the front to cover that, I think. Have a look.

Comment: @JaZZyCooL , is it now answering your question?